# CSS3 Creative Div Box Design | CSS Animation Effects

Tags: javascript, css

I was making a CSS box design. when I'm done I saw my website keep moving up and down at below, then I saw my background color had 2 but just a little at the bottom. when I try to delete coding @keyframes animate my website was stopping moving and down. can you help me
here my coding at CSS file

```css
.square {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
  border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
}

.square:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}

.square span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
  border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

.square:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}

.square span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
  border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: animate2 10s linear infinite;
}

.square:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  border: none;
  background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.content1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 60px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <div class="content1">
    <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no
      one else in the city knows about. Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has a different kind of feel.”</p>

  </div>


</div>
```

I hope I can get feedback very soon for my assignment

Comment: hello. add your html, pls.

Comment: Can't say anything without the html

Comment: i was post html coding just now

Answer (score 0):

for your case, best way is to control your width and height and reduce value of them or make a box and use `overflow:hidden` in parent div because borders that you set absolute position for them, they are bigger from your page.

**NOTE:**
if you want add more content below this code or you have content above it, use `overflow-x:hidden` for this div, if it dosen't work, use `overflow-x:hidden` for your body tag.

sorry for my grammar.

```css
body{
 /*overflow-x:hidden*/
}
.square{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;/*if using overflow-x for body set width to 100vw or if use overflow:hidden for .square set width to 400px*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.square span:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
    border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: animate 6s linear infinite ;

}

.square:hover span:nth-child(1){
    border: none;
    background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}

.square span:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
    border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;

}

.square:hover span:nth-child(2){
    border: none;
    background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}
.square span:nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(228, 43, 73);
    border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 41% 44% 56% 59%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: animate2 10s linear infinite;

}

.square:hover span:nth-child(3){
    border: none;
    background: rgb(233, 112, 132);
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes animate2{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.content1{
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 1000;
    

}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <div class="content1">
        <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her little oasis just this morning. 
            If you have ever spotted a coffee shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you 
            know the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. Elizabeth’s nook is 
            that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has a different kind of feel.”</p>

    </div>


</div>
```